# Is there a way to detect in Chrome whether a HTTP server is responding?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

I have a script, which loads a certain address into a child window and works on that. If I cannot access the loaded document I'd like to know whether the browser loaded the Chrome error page because the network or the server is down or I got an error because I did not disable security and site isolation for the actual window. I got the same `DOMException{stack: 'Error: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.` in both scenario. I thought on using `navigator.onLine` and/or checking with XHR as possible solutions, but I am not sure if this is possible. I don't want to experiment for days if not necessary. Is there anybody who solved this?

conclusion:

I ended up using a modified version of the accepted answer with async functions:

```js
async function isAlive(url) {
  try {
    await fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
    return true;
  } catch(error){
    return false;
  }
}
    
(async function main(){
  const addresses = [
    'https://google.com',
    'https://reallyf4kewebsite.com',
    '/',
    'https://google.com/foo/bar/baz'
  ];
  const results = await Promise.all(addresses.map((address) => isAlive(address)));
  addresses.forEach((address, index) => console.log(address, results[index]));
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know if a server is alive by doing a no-cors request to it.

But you won't be able to get any more info than that, i.e an error redirect (404, 501, etc.) will be seen as alive.

That is because, while this mode allows us to send requests as if there were no CORS limitations, the Response you'll get is actually opaque, and no other information than *"The URL mapped to some response"* will be accessible to our scripts.

```js
function isAlive(url) {
  return fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(r => true)
    .catch(r => false);
}

isAlive('https://google.com')
  .then(r => console.log('google', r));
  
isAlive('https://reallyf4kewebsite.com')
  .then(r => console.log('reallyf4kewebsite', r));
  
isAlive('/')
  .then(r => console.log('stacksnippets', r));

isAlive('https://google.com/foo/bar/baz')
  .then(r => console.log('404 redirect', r));
```